# How to create python dataframe from nested json dictionary with increasing key

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

I have a json file with the following structure:

```
{'0': {'transaction': [{'transaction_key': '406.l.657872.tr.374',
    'transaction_id': '374',
    'type': 'add/drop',
    'status': 'successful',
    'timestamp': '1639593953'},
   {'players': {'0': {'player': [[{'player_key': '406.p.100006'},
        {'player_id': '100006'},
        {'name': {'full': 'Dallas',
          'first': 'Dallas',
          'last': '',
          'ascii_first': 'Dallas',
          'ascii_last': ''}},
        {'editorial_team_abbr': 'Dal'},
        {'display_position': 'DEF'},
        {'position_type': 'DT'}],
       {'transaction_data': [{'type': 'add',
          'source_type': 'freeagents',
          'destination_type': 'team',
          'destination_team_key': '406.l.657872.t.10',
          'destination_team_name': 'Team 1'}]}]},
     '1': {'player': [[{'player_key': '406.p.24793'},
        {'player_id': '24793'},
        {'name': {'full': 'Julio Jones',
          'first': 'Julio',
          'last': 'Jones',
          'ascii_first': 'Julio',
          'ascii_last': 'Jones'}},
        {'editorial_team_abbr': 'Ten'},
        {'display_position': 'WR'},
        {'position_type': 'O'}],
       {'transaction_data': {'type': 'drop',
         'source_type': 'team',
         'source_team_key': '406.l.657872.t.10',
         'source_team_name': 'Team 1',
         'destination_type': 'waivers'}}]},
     'count': 2}}]},
 '1': {'transaction': [{'transaction_key': '406.l.657872.tr.373',
    'transaction_id': '373',
    'type': 'add/drop',
    'status': 'successful',
    'timestamp': '1639575496'},
   {'players': {'0': {'player': [[{'player_key': '406.p.32722'},
        {'player_id': '32722'},
        {'name': {'full': 'Cam Akers',
          'first': 'Cam',
          'last': 'Akers',
          'ascii_first': 'Cam',
          'ascii_last': 'Akers'}},
        {'editorial_team_abbr': 'LAR'},
        {'display_position': 'RB'},
        {'position_type': 'O'}],
       {'transaction_data': [{'type': 'add',
          'source_type': 'freeagents',
          'destination_type': 'team',
          'destination_team_key': '406.l.657872.t.5',
          'destination_team_name': 'Team 2'}]}]},
     '1': {'player': [[{'player_key': '406.p.100007'},
        {'player_id': '100007'},
        {'name': {'full': 'Denver',
          'first': 'Denver',
          'last': '',
          'ascii_first': 'Denver',
          'ascii_last': ''}},
        {'editorial_team_abbr': 'Den'},
        {'display_position': 'DEF'},
        {'position_type': 'DT'}],
       {'transaction_data': {'type': 'drop',
         'source_type': 'team',
         'source_team_key': '406.l.657872.t.5',
         'source_team_name': 'Team 2',
         'destination_type': 'waivers'}}]},
     'count': 2}}]},
 '2': {'transaction': [{'transaction_key': '406.l.657872.tr.372',
    'transaction_id': '372',
    'type': 'add/drop',
    'status': 'successful',
    'timestamp': '1639575448'},
   {'players': {'0': {'player': [[{'player_key': '406.p.33413'},
        {'player_id': '33413'},
        {'name': {'full': 'Travis Etienne',
          'first': 'Travis',
          'last': 'Etienne',
          'ascii_first': 'Travis',
          'ascii_last': 'Etienne'}},
        {'editorial_team_abbr': 'Jax'},
        {'display_position': 'RB'},
        {'position_type': 'O'}],
       {'transaction_data': [{'type': 'add',
          'source_type': 'freeagents',
          'destination_type': 'team',
          'destination_team_key': '406.l.657872.t.5',
          'destination_team_name': 'Team 2'}]}]},
     '1': {'player': [[{'player_key': '406.p.24815'},
        {'player_id': '24815'},
        {'name': {'full': 'Mark Ingram II',
          'first': 'Mark',
          'last': 'Ingram II',
          'ascii_first': 'Mark',
          'ascii_last': 'Ingram II'}},
        {'editorial_team_abbr': 'NO'},
        {'display_position': 'RB'},
        {'position_type': 'O'}],
       {'transaction_data': {'type': 'drop',
         'source_type': 'team',
         'source_team_key': '406.l.657872.t.5',
         'source_team_name': 'Team 2',
         'destination_type': 'waivers'}}]},
     'count': 2}}]}
```

These are transactions for a fantasy football league and I'd like to organize each transaction into a dataframe, however I'm running into issues normalizing the data. I figure I'd need to begin a loop, but am slightly stuck in the mud and would appreciate if anyone has any suggestions. Thank You.

Ideally, I'm looking to summarize each transaction with the following dataframe structure:

```
transaction_id  type     added          pos_1  dropped        pos_2  timestamp
374             add/drop Dallas         DEF    Julio Jones    WR     1639593953
373             add/drop Cam Akers      RB     Denver         DEF    1639575496
372             add/drop Travis Etienne RB     Mark Ingram II RB     1639575448
```

Comment: Please include your desired dataframe.

Comment: Apologies, I've edited my post.